# I can't paste my code in stackoverflow.com

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I tried copy & paste and after reading meta Q&A I also tried http://pastebin.com,
nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Copy your code. Paste it into the editor box. Make sure there is at least one blank line above it if you want to paste a block of code. Select it and press <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>. It will be formatted as code.

```
This is my
Amazing
PHP
Code
```

Comment: I did follow you instructions, so everything sort of worked - but I got this message "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

    Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon"

Comment: @ManavBrar: Can you edit your question to include your entire question, formatted as code?

Comment: @ManavBrar to make sure you understand - edit your question **here** so we can see what might be wrong. :)

Comment: @minitechη, I see what you're trying to do, but asking the OP to include everything as a code block when the question is about inability to use code blocks seems kind of... can't think of a good word... futile, I guess.

Comment: @PopularDemand: No, I think the OP understands how to format it, but the system isn't recognizing what's code and what's not correctly. So I'm just trying to see if this is the editor being a little too strict.